# What could be burning the schottky diode in this synchronous rectifier?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, rectifier

I have [this TV PSU](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rFFFK875TbX5dwTEC2U4gvOVC8pcl-ZJ) which has one supply circuit for the TV motherboard, which it calls "standby" in the scheme (AO3).

Here's a portion of the AO3 circuit where most of the components I'll mention are:

Primary side with PWM controller:

[image]

Secondary side with synchronous rectifier:

[image]

This PSU died and then I've found that the schottky diode D9311 was shorted.

I've replaced it and then, for some reason, it wouldn't work.

The voltage on 12VS (where it should be 12 V) was oscillating erratically from 8 to 16 V, and dropped to way lower values like 4 to 7 V if I connected a 200 ohm resistor from 12VS to GND.

The PWM controller on the primary side (U9301) also had a fluctuating voltage on its VCC and it has 0 V on the feedback pin (the COMP pin).

Its VCC was supposed to be fed (after startup) by the transformer too, but it wasn't producing enough voltage in that VCC1 line, it was a mere 2.5 V, lower than the fluctuating voltage on the cathode side of diode D9393.

So I took an external source of 18 V and fed it to VCC1. This made things start to get right, now the voltage on the VCC pin was also around 18 V, voltage on the COMP pin was 1.2 V and the voltage on the secondary side, where it should be 12 V, was 8.6 V, stable 8.6 V.

I figured it should be because it was in standby, so I applied 5 V to PS_ON and I finally got stable 12 V on the secondary side...

...Until it burned D9311 again.

What could be happening here?

If I understood it correctly, if the MOSFET Q9303 were not switching, then D9311 would be acting as a rectifier by itself, but would be under a much greater load than when Q9303 is working properly.

Could that be the reason? Could Q9303 not being switched and then overloading D9311?

But I tested this MOSFET already, and it seems to be working fine (out of the circuit).

Plus I don't quite understand why would the PSU be oscillating wildly in that way before, and why feeding 18 V to the VCC pin of the PWM controller made it stop.

I'm failing to understand if there's a single problem here or if there is two, one that destroys D9311 and another that makes the PWM controller to fail to start without aid from an external source.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried feeding the 12V side from a power supply or battery? There could be a fault in the load.

Comment: @Kartman Load? There's no load right now, the PSU disconnected from the TV.

Comment: @Kartman And if there was something shorting the secondary, I'd expect it to be doing so when it was fluctuating between 8 to 16 V. When I added a 200 ohm resistor as load it dropped a lot, so there is seemingly no load on the secondary.

Comment: The diode D9311 is a 5A 100V Schottky barrier diode. Its quite beefy, So if it failed, then a current larger than 5A must have passed through it for a long period of time or a reverse voltage greater than 100V must have appeared across it. Apart from that, I can't imagine why it would fail. But at the same time, its hard to imagine that either of the things happened.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth yes, specially when there is apparently no load on the secondary. If anything was shorted out in there then it would be nonsense for an added 200 ohm load to drop the voltage like that (when it was oscillating). I guess I'll have to test running the circuit without the schottky (in which case it should still work, because the MOSFET is the main conducing element in that rectifier) and see what's what. And maybe, after replacing, I should put an ammeter in series with the mosfet+schottky to measure what currents appear.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth things just got more confusing now. Without the schottky, the power supply started working once again (with that auxiliary 18 V source, just like it was before burning the schottky).